# GCF with passport JS

Tags: passport.js, google-cloud-functions

We are trying to use cloud functions, but we are struggling with authentication. 
On our node.js application (running on GAE)  we are using Passport.js
Is it possible to use the same mechanism for GCF to authenticate the requests?

Comment: Just to confirm I'm understanding your inquiry correctly. You basically have something like an endpoint in your cloud function and you want to authenticate the ingress requests, right?